# Switching classes and functions dynamically based on string values from tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

Hi I have got a requirement to extract various reports from our project management system into tables. Around 28 reports.

So initially I thought about extracting it in different blocks based on the report IDs like this

```
                        switch (reportId)
                        {
                            
                            case 737://project static
                                
                                
                                KipReport<ApiProjectStatic> rptPS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport<ApiProjectStatic>>(responseBody,dateTimeConverter);
                                List<ApiProjectStatic> jsonPS = (List<ApiProjectStatic>)rptPS.Data;
                                //jsonPS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectStaticMain>>(rpt.Data);
                                List<KipProjectStatic> PM = new List<KipProjectStatic>();
                                PM = _mapper.Map<List<KipProjectStatic>>(jsonPS);
                                PM.Select(p => { p.LogId = log.LogId; return p; }).ToList();
                                _context.KipProjectStatics.AddRange(PM);
                                _context.SaveChanges();
                                if (rptPS.TotalPages > 1 && rptPS.PageNumber != rptPS.TotalPages)
                                {
                                    GetKeyedinReport(reportId, rptPS.PageNumber + 1,log);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 740:
                                 .....
                                 .....
```

For every reports what changes here is the classnames and Context objects. So my question is, is there any way to switch those classes from string names coming from tables

For example I have a table like this

```
Report ID     ReportName                ModelClass          JSONClass            Context
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
737           Project Details         KipProjectStatic      ApiProjectStatic     KipProjectStatics
738           Program rreport         KipProgramme          ApiProgramme         KipProgrammes
.....
...
.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So we are looping through these data and switches the functions and classes based on the string values coming from different columns. Hope its clear

Also here GetKeyedinReport function is always the same for all reports.. It just returns the json based on the ID we pass

Please share a solution

Comment: You can create an object using `Activator.CreateInstance("SomeClassName")`. If the various classes (in the same category) have the same call interface, then you can create an `interface` that they implement. Then you can do something like `var model = (IModel)Activator.CreateInstance("KipProgramme");` if `KipProgramme` is declared to implement `IModel`

Comment: To create a generic object (like `KipReport<ApiProjectStatic>`), you'll need to create the type object using `Type.MakeGenericType`. Other than that. It's pretty much the same

Comment: Sorry to ask, it would be great if you can make an answer replacing my code with a generic way as you suggested. I am a little confused..